# Random server error (error establishing database connection) - (too many users) Wordpress - how to identify script/plugin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, internal-server-error

Just since this morning, a website starts showing 500 server errors. The errors occur completely random, on every page it occurs sometimes. Reload the page several times will show the content again.
The website is Wordpress. The error users see:

grey screen with "error establishing database connection"

debug provides the following warning:

"user XXXX already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections"

How do I identify the specific file/script/plugin that causes these issues?

Comment: Is it always user "XXXX" or sometimes another user ?  When it is always user "XXXX" disable that account and see if the problem get away.

Comment: There is only one user I gues, just the user specified in the Wordpress config file

Comment: It's also possible that your max connections limit is set too low for the site.

Comment: It's set at 20, cannot edit it because it is shared hosting